# "Invalid datetime format. value:2020-01-07 11:46:44" with elasticsearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm having an issue when I try to retrieve information from elasticsearch.

when i do a simple query :

```
var searchResponse = client.Search<injectedData>(s => s.MatchAll());
```

I catch an `invalid datetime format. value:2020-01-07 11:46:44` as error

What I don't understand is that I specify the exact format when I serialize DateTime

```
public class MyDateTimeConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public MyDateTimeConverter()
    {
        DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    }
}

class injectedData
{
    public String Id { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(MyDateTimeConverter))]
    public DateTime process_start_time { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(MyDateTimeConverter))]
    public DateTime item_start_time { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(MyDateTimeConverter))]
    public DateTime item_end_time { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(MyDateTimeConverter))]
    public DateTime end_time { get; set; }

    public long process_execution_duration { get; set; }
    public int metadata_type { get; set; }
    public String machine { get; set; }
    public String windows_session { get; set; }
    public String proces_name { get; set; }
    public String item { get; set; }
}
```

The mapping looks like this

```
{
  "properties": {
    "process_start_time": {
      "type": "date",
      "format":"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    },
    "item_start_time": {
        "type": "date",
      "format":"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    },
    "item_end_time": {
        "type":"date",
      "format":"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    },
    "end_time": {
        "type":"date",
      "format":"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    }
  }
}
```

I can't seem to understand where the issue is coming from. Does someone have an idea?

***update 14: 01: 2020***

So it seems, that if I insert data without a mapping in the base time format yyyyDDD'T'HHmmss.SSSZ  "Like this "2019-07-04T05:53:00,544" I don't have any issues.

Can't I work with custom date format if I use nest?

Comment: can you search a specific record you know to be in the correct format? Is it possible you have older data that doesnt conform to this?

Comment: Hey Jawad, thank you for your reply. I checked and added the right index in the query so to be sure I'm not going to look in another index as well. But the problem keeps being present. The format issue is for "process_start_time" in my first document. I can't seem to make any queries whatsoever :/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I don't know why I couldn't work with custom dateFormat but I've changed the format to the time basic format everywhere and it works now. I still don't get why it didn't work the way I did previously but I guess you can't or I missed something somewhere.